# How to add a progress bar in scrapy for downloading video?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, tqdm

I made a spider in scrapy that downloads the videos from this page which has some 10-20 videos one by one using media pipelines. So i want to make a progress bar so that it doesn't look stuck and after finishing a video it will show appropriate message. Some suggests to use tqdm but i don't really know how to implement that in scrapy.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue on scrapy github repo:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3793

In that case progress bar added using `tqdm` library methods inside http handler.

Comment: I have gone through it but not able to figure out how and where to implement that in my project. I tried using #print(response.headers.getlist('content-length')) to get the size of downloadable but not getting anything printed. I am new to scrapy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It’s a work-in-progress issue, Scrapy does not currently support tracking download progress, and it won’t until https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3793 is closed and a version with the feature is released.